# Calling a javascript function asynchronosly from server side in c#

Tags: c#, javascript

this is my code :

```
protected void BtnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   List<DataTable> tb = Helper.SplitTableToManyTables(FileTb, 50); // a list containing multiple DataTable each have 50 rows
        int importedRowsCount = 0;
        for (int KLoop = 0; KLoop < tb.Count; KLoop++)
        { 
        ...
   if (QueriesDataHelper.ImportContacts(resTb, int.Parse(TxtHiddenGroupId.Value), Session)) 
            {
                importedRowsCount += resTb.Rows.Count;
                var script = "DisplayProgressMsg(" + importedRowsCount + ")";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "MyScript", script, true);
                if (KLoop == tb.Count - 1)
                    MessageBox.Show(importedRowsCount.ToString()+" Contacts imported successfully");
            }
    }
}
```

QueriesDataHelper.ImportContacts is a function that take a dataTable containing 50 rows and send it to a stored procedure

my problem is RegisterStartupScript is beeing executed after all the dataTables are beiing inserted i want to display a ms after the first DataTable finish tha

Comment: Do you want to display ms for each consequence row? Or only after first one?

Comment: when the first 50 rows is inserted i want to display a msg that 50 rows are inserted then when the other 50 is inserted i update this msg to say 100 rows are inserted and so on like a update progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

Http is request/response protocol. But you want send do multiple responses for single request.

I see two ways for you. In both, you will have to run your long running process in separate thread. Then

1) use ajax, to ask server about progress every N seconds, and display result. Client's will track progress with some delay

2) web sockets([SignalR](http://signalr.net/) is great for such purposes). In this way you will be able to display progress in real time, but i think it's harder to implement

Comment: umm yeah i used SignalR before and it's not the good solution for me now bcs of it's implementation but if i want to use option 1 how can i do it in my case within my code ? can u provide an example ? please